# Error Uploading image to google cloud storage from Google app engine php app

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to upload images to Google cloud storage using CKeditor4.3.3 image2 plugin from google engine app (php).

POst method return 303 status.

GET returns:
Request URL:http://temporary-blobstore-error.appspot.com/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Request Headersview source

I get the following error displayed fromhttp://temporary-blobstore-error.appspot.com/:
Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please retry your last submission.

If the problem persists, please contact the person responsible for the application you're using, or, if you are that person, report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.

Following is the Request URL:
[http://v01.mysite.appspot.com/_ah/upload/?aa=ask&cat=2/AMmfu6aYRdoHF3NpG27hJRWyx-RH_Vo5r6NhzqyIK-3YRw7I3OHv_zq6SUYElQKg3phbtFu6GIG_MnltZjS03xNPSDKfA-dmsabvdvdmavdmavmvamdsvmdVMDVAMVmadva-e_rmabsmdvdmsdbmsdbmabdmasbdmasbdmsmdYR2MuM7rBb6dEttPzPYVylmw9/ALBNUaYAAAAAUy-nio2CLZdkumm87rKdUq9oOz1hVJgN/&CKEditor=content&CKEditorFuncNum=0&langCode=en][1]

Comment: I assume your app id is "mysite"?

Comment: For safety I have replaced my actual GAE ID with mysite.

Comment: 303 is expected after an upload. It's a redirection to the url that you specified when calling CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl(). See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload